# Apple iMac powermac 6.1

Tags: iphone, imac, power-mac

How Come my old iMac Powermac 6.1 isn't recognized by my iPhone 4s ? and how do I connect my mobile hotspot from my T-Mobile iPhone 4s to my old iMac Power Mac 6.1? I try to just plug it in with the USB cable but the iMac seems to not recognize it at all .

Comment: Please use commas when referring to model numbers (`6,1`). Your iMac has a PowerPC processor. No moderns forward uses this architecture anymore, so iTunes isn't updates with support for it. Does your iMac have an AirPort card?

Comment: That would be one of [those](http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=PowerMac6%2C1), correct?

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is provided by https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-6021.  This explains the maximum version of OS X which is supported by your particular system (10.5.8), as well as the maximum version of iOS which your phone can be in order to be recognised by the computer (iOS 5.x and earlier).  If you are able to meet both these conditions, you should be able to connect the phone to your computer and have it recognised (which should be the condition needed to start network sharing via USB).

It will also depend as to whether you have the optional Airport card installed in the mac, or the optional Bluetooth capability, as this will help you with your network sharing options from your iPhone.

If you've got a version of iOS on your phone that is 6.x or later, then you're probably out of luck for being able to get the phone and computer to talk to each other effectively as there's no real downgrade path available.